# Excel VBA 2013 - Easy way to bring back on top opened userform after workbook opened

Tags: excel, modal-dialog, userform, vba

I'm using Userform in Modal mode and I open a Workbook from VBA.

When the workbook is opened, I'd like to bring back the calling Userform to the top, letting the workbook backward waiting for later updating.

Is there any simple VBA statement to implement that ?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the following statement:

```
UserForm1.Show 0  'vbModeless = 0
```

Or

```
UserForm1.Show vbModal 'vbModal = 1
```

Comment: The Userform is still shown and also vbModal.
The error Userform is already Opened is fired...

The idea is to make the userform activated or as activewindow

I did not know how to get it simply. Seems to have to use Windows System switching. No worthy to obtain the expected result.